# If case in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure :

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetApplicationByCostCentreId]
(    
  @CostCentreId TINYINT,
  @DepartmentId INT = NULL,
  @IsActive BIT = NULL
)
AS 

BEGIN
    SELECT 
        A.Id, A.Name, A.URL, 
        A.CostCentreId, C.CostCentre,
        A.DepartmentId, D.DepartmentName,
        A.ApplicationOwnerTypeId, AOT.Type,
        A.SupportContact,
        A.IsActive, A.AddedOn, A.AddedBy, A.ModifiedOn, A.ModifiedBy
    FROM 
        dbo.Applications A
        INNER JOIN dbo.Central_CostCentre_Main C ON A.CostCentreId = C.CostCentreId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Central_Department_Main D ON A.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ApplicationOwnerType AOT ON A.ApplicationOwnerTypeId = AOT.Id
    WHERE    
        A.CostCentreId = @CostCentreId
    AND CASE WHEN @DepartmentId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN A.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1
    AND CASE WHEN @IsActive IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN A.IsActive = @IsActive THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1
    ORDER BY [Name]
END
```

Now in this procedure if i pass @DepartmentId=24 then I get results only for department 24, however I want it to display results with @DepartmentId=24 and for departmentsId = null

How should I modify procedure to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as your where clause:

```
WHERE    
    A.CostCentreId = @CostCentreId AND 
    (A.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId OR A.DepartmentId IS NULL 
        OR @DepartmentId IS NULL) /* also return row if the arg is null */ AND
    A.IsActive = ISNULL(@IsActive, 1)
ORDER BY [Name]
```

**EDIT:** You could possibly also try:

```
WHERE    
    A.CostCentreId = @CostCentreId AND 
    (ISNULL(A.DepartmentId, @DepartmentId) = @DepartmentId 
        OR @DepartmentId IS NULL) /* also return row if the arg is null */ AND
    A.IsActive = ISNULL(@IsActive, 1)
ORDER BY [Name]
```

Comment: Thanks ,This works partially. If '@DepartmentId' is null and only '@CostCentreId' is provided i get zero rows. In short it only works when '@DepartmentId' is provided. i want it either way..

Comment: Please see my edited answer. That should take care of null parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE COALESCE(A.DepartmentId, 'x') = COALESCE(@DepartmentId, A.DepartmentId, 'x')
```

assuming `'x'` is a valid value of type `DepartmentId` but does not exist in the domain.

However, consider that you may get better performance using a series of `IF` blocks.